# How to list categories of posts which belong to a custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom taxonomy called ausgabe (german for issue - for a magazine). I wish to get a list of the categories that the posts assigned to that category have. I do not wish to get the sub-categories of the custom taxonomy, since the categories are standard WP categories.

I have tried the following, but it is displaying all categories from the site.

Appreciate any help.

```html
<?php

$al_cat_slug = get_queried_object()->slug;

$al_tax_post_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'ausgabe',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $al_cat_slug,
        )
    )
);

$terms = get_posts( $al_tax_post_args);

$categories = get_categories($terms);

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo "$category->name <br/>";


} //end foreach

wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Where do you put this code? Get_queried_object can not be used in archive or any where without the loop, it needs one object. What exactly are you trying to achieve, did not get that. You are displaying a single post and want to show all category terms assigned to this post?

Comment: Just to clarify - you have many posts in `ausgabe` and you want a list of all the default WP categories assigned to them, is that correct?

Comment: I am placing this code in taxonomy-ausgabe.php
My aim is to first pull all the posts that belong to my custom tax, but in an array and then list the categories that belong to those. The output should only be a list of categories that belong to the posts in the custom tax.